# How to get id from url parameter to url function codeigniter4

Tags: codeigniter, url, parameters, model, get

How to get id from url parameter to url function codeigniter4

```
 public function show($id = null)
    {

        $data = $this->model->where('id', $id)->findAll();
        if ($data) {
            return $this->respond($data, 200);
        } else {
            return $this->failNotFound("Data Not Found to $id");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value using post request.
and in controller function you can read like this

```
public function show( ) {
  $id = $this->request->getVar('id');
  $data = $this->model->where('id', $id)->findAll();
  if ($data) {
    return $this->respond($data, 200);
  } else {
    return $this->failNotFound("Data Not Found to $id");
  }
}
```

Comment: I want the id on the link it doesn't appear

Comment: You can send id using post request.
I have updated the answer.

Comment: Undefined property $input.. how to solve this? btw thank you

Comment: but i am using codeigniter4 and extends basecontroller, how?

Comment: I've updated the answer. $id = $this->request->getVar('id'); This will get id from your request.